# How do I select all matches in a database that have two particular players?

Tags: mysql, sql

The situation:

Matches have 10 players, 5 on each team. There are 100 players total and each match can have any player in any of the ten spots. I need to extract the following given two players:

1. How many matches were player A and player B allies?
2. How many of these did they win?
3. How many matches were player A and player B opponents?
4. How many of these did player A win?

My current method (too slow and possibly doesn't work):

I've made three tables, "players", "matches" and "matches_players" which maps the matches to the players that played in them. The column "winning_team" in matches represents which team won (0 = team A, 1 = team B) and column "position" in the matches_players table represents what spot the player was in the lineup. 0-4 is on team A, 5-9 is on team B.

---

players

---

```
player_id
43179582
63260623
31250276
54829050
22257854
etc...
```

---

matches

---

```
match_id     winning_team
95824317     0
06236326     0
02763125     1
90505482     0
78544325     1
etc...
```

---

matches_players

---

```
relation_id     match_id     player_id     position
1               95824317     43179582      1
2               95824317     63260623      5
3               06236326     43179582      7
4               06236326     54829050      0
5               06236326     22257854      4
etc...
```

Here's the statement I'm using for finding match and win counts of heroes on the same team (after over 12 hours of surfing and trying to understand SQL):

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS match_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN team = winning_team THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS win_count
FROM
    (SELECT
    matches.match_id,
    (CASE WHEN position < 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS team,
    winning_team
    FROM matches INNER JOIN matches_players ON matches.match_id = matches_players.match_id
    WHERE player_id = [____] OR player_id = [____]
    GROUP BY match_id, team HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
AS pair_matches
```

It seems to work, but it's incredibly slow (90+ secs on 250,000 matches) and ideally I'd like to have opposing team results in the same query (which should be faster than two separate queries, no?) Can the query be made faster/better? Is there a database design flaw?

I really appreciate any help guys. Advice in any area is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: How can you tell which team a player is on in a given match?

Comment: For speed...I'd look into indexing first.  Might be a logic issue though...most databases will return an error if you attempt to group by some fields, but exclude others (winning team isn't in your group by statement).  WHere other databases return errors, MySQL just returns one randomly it seems.

Comment: Their team can be found by their "position" in the matches_players table. A position of 0-4 means they're on team A, 5-9 means team B. 

Twelfth, the match_id and player_id fields are indexed and have a foreign key linking the tables. Do you mean I need to index other columns? I'll add winning_team to the GROUP BY and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it or at least give you a hint

```
-- How many matches were player A and player B allies?
select DISTINCT (match_id) from MATCHES_PLAYERS where PLAYER_ID='43179582' or PLAYER_ID='63260623' group by MATCH_ID;

-- How many of these did they win?
select  PLAYER_ID, count(WINNING_TEAM)
from 
(select  PLAYER_ID, WINNING_TEAM, POsition from MATCHES_PLAYERS mp, matches m where mp.MATCH_ID=m.MATCH_ID and position<=4 and WINNING_TEAM=0
union all
select PLAYER_ID, WINNING_TEAM, POsition from MATCHES_PLAYERS mp, matches m where mp.MATCH_ID=m.MATCH_ID and position>4 and WINNING_TEAM=1)
group by PLAYER_id;

-- How many matches were player A and player B opponents?
select mp1.*, m.WINNING_TEAM, mp2.PLAYER_ID as opponent from MATCHES_PLAYERS mp1, MATCHES_PLAYERS mp2, matches m where mp1.MATCH_ID=m.MATCH_ID and  mp1.MATCH_ID=mp2.MATCH_ID and mp1.PLAYER_ID!=mp2.PLAYER_ID and (mp1.PLAYER_id in (43179582, 63260623) and mp2.player_id in (43179582, 63260623))
select DISTINCT mp1.MATCH_ID from MATCHES_PLAYERS mp1, MATCHES_PLAYERS mp2, matches m where mp1.MATCH_ID=m.MATCH_ID and  mp1.MATCH_ID=mp2.MATCH_ID and mp1.PLAYER_ID!=mp2.PLAYER_ID and (mp1.PLAYER_id in (43179582, 63260623) and mp2.player_id in (43179582, 63260623))

-- How many of these did player A win?
select
mp1.*, m.WINNING_TEAM, mp2.PLAYER_ID as opponent
from MATCHES_PLAYERS mp1, MATCHES_PLAYERS mp2, matches m
where mp1.MATCH_ID=m.MATCH_ID
and mp1.MATCH_ID=mp2.MATCH_ID
and mp1.PLAYER_ID!=mp2.PLAYER_ID
and
(
   mp1.PLAYER_id=43179582
   and mp2.player_id=63260623
)
and mp1.position<=4
and m.WINNING_TEAM=0
```

Comment: I only just now (over a year later) saw this answer. The issue has long been resolved and I'm much better at SQL now, but I just wanted to say thanks for putting the time in. I'm sorry I didn't see it before. It would have been a big help at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that that there is a mistake in the accepted answer (in the "How many matches were player A and B allies?" section)

My answer uses subqueries and ROUND(position/4) to convert from position 0..3 to team 0 and from position 4..7 to team 1.

First, this script creates tables (Oracle SQL flavour). Indexes are only created on primaries keys automatically:

```
CREATE TABLE players(player_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE matches(match_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, winning_team NUMBER(1) CHECK(winning_team IN (0, 1)));
CREATE TABLE matches_players(relation_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, match_id NUMBER NOT NULL REFERENCES matches(match_id), player_id NUMBER NOT NULL REFERENCES players(player_id), position NUMBER NOT NULL CHECK(position < 8));
```

Let's load some data:

```
INSERT INTO players
SELECT 43179582 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 63260623 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 31250276 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 54829050 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 22257854 FROM DUAL
;

-- match_id     winning_team
INSERT INTO matches
SELECT 95824317, 0 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 06236326, 0 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 02763125, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 90505482, 0 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 78544325, 1 FROM DUAL
;

-- relation_id     match_id     player_id     position
DELETE matches_players;
INSERT INTO matches_players
SELECT 1, 95824317, 43179582, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 95824317, 63260623, 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 06236326, 43179582, 7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 06236326, 54829050, 0 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 06236326, 22257854, 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 06236326, 63260623, 4 FROM DUAL
;
```

And then, these are the queries:

```
-- How many matches were player A and player B allies?
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matches_players mp WHERE player_id = 63260623
AND (match_id, ROUND(position/4)) IN (
    SELECT match_id, ROUND(position/4) FROM matches_players WHERE player_id = 22257854
);

-- How many of these did they win?
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matches_players mp WHERE player_id = 63260623
AND (match_id, ROUND(position/4)) IN (
    SELECT match_id, ROUND(position/4) FROM matches_players WHERE player_id = 22257854
)
AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM matches m WHERE m.match_id = mp.match_id AND m.winning_team = ROUND(mp.position/4))
;

-- How many matches were player A and player B opponents?
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matches_players mp WHERE player_id = 63260623
AND (match_id, ROUND(position/4)) IN (
    SELECT match_id, -(ROUND(position/4) - 1) FROM matches_players WHERE player_id = 54829050
);

-- How many of these did player A win?
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matches_players mp WHERE player_id = 54829050
AND (match_id, ROUND(position/4)) IN (
    SELECT match_id, -(ROUND(position/4) - 1) FROM matches_players WHERE player_id = 63260623
)
AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM matches m WHERE m.match_id = mp.match_id AND m.winning_team = ROUND(mp.position/4))
;
```

If you want to speed those queries up, you can create indexes on position and winning_team:

```
CREATE INDEX matches_idx ON matches(winning_team);
CREATE INDEX matches_players_idx ON matches_players(ROUND(position/4));
```

And if you want ultra-speed and your database engine supports bitmap indexes, you can try:

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX matches_idx ON matches(winning_team);
CREATE BITMAP INDEX matches_players_idx ON matches_players(ROUND(position/4));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately that project is long gone at this point. I might work on something similar soon though, so it might come in handy. Just curious, why did you answer such an old post?

Comment: Because it's an intemporal question :D